# Why wont this button work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uibutton

I have this button set up to start the game, but all it does is spawn a button in for a second then automatically start the game. The button just pops up then goes away after about .5 second. Is this a coding issue?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour {

    #region Fields
    private int buttonWidth = 200;
    private int buttonHeight = 50;
    private string instructionText = "Instrucions:\nPress Left and Right     Arrows to Move.\nPress Space Bar to Fire.";
    #endregion


    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect (10, 10, 250, 200), instructionText);
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - buttonWidth / 2, Screen.height / 2 - buttonHeight / 2, buttonWidth, buttonHeight), "Start Game"));

        {
            Application.LoadLevel(1);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Yep that worked thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting the semicolon at the end of the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

The semi colon at the end of the if loop causes the Application.LoadLevel(1) to Always be called.

Comment: Doesn't it mean that Application.LoadLevel(1) is always called regardless of the return value of GUI.Button? Which is why the application automatically starts.

Comment: @PaulF I am not sure now you come to mention it, i think it does not.But i am not sure let me go test a script.

Comment: It will run it, the semi-colon at the end just makes the block underneath it not part of the "if" statement, so it should run regardless of the check.

Comment: @PaulF yea just checked it always runs my bad :P

Answer (score 0):

When you place a semicolon in front of an if statement it ends it and it won't continue to "Application.LoadLevel(1);". Remove the semicolon so that it considers that line as parte of the if.

Comment: See the comments above - the semicolon just terminates the if statement - the code continues to Application.LoadLevel(1) which is why it starts automatically after a short time.

Comment: Sorry I explained wrong what I wanted to say is that that line wasn't part of the if so it wont mater if it enter the if to execute that line.